# What does this "in" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, word-meaning

> Ginsberg and Power were friends and, briefly, lovers. The piece is both raw and complex **in** thinking through their friendship and how we mourn.[Source](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/books/2014/03/weekend-reading-rob-ford-chronicles-bohemian-waitresses-and-more.html)

What does this "in" mean?

As a sidenote, I don't know how the lover is used here. Is the word used like this in a friendly meaning? Not a serious love relationship?

Comment: Lol. Off-topic. Really?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  It's clear what you're asking about now.

Comment: "Lovers" -- when describing a relationship between two people -- is always going to imply a sexual relationship.

Answer (score 3):

The **in** stands for something like "in that it is", "while", "as it is" or "when" in this sentence.

The mentioned complexity and rawness are found in how the said piece "thinks" through their friendship and how we mourn.

The "thinking through" would give me more trouble in understanding the sentence, honestly, but in the context I assume the writer means that the piece shows how the author reminisces about the friendship and explores how we mourn.

Basically, the *reason* to call the piece raw and complex is the way it deals with their friendship and the way we mourn. We don't know whether it is raw or complex when it talks about other subjects. Actually, we don't even know if the piece deals with any other subjects. Obviously, the writer of the article thought these two themes were the most important - and they make the piece raw and complex.

As to you sidenote: I have no reason to believe that the word "lovers" is used here to indicate anything else than the fact the two people mentioned were involved in a romantic relationship. It doesn't necessarily mean they were *in love* or that they felt they had a meaningful, long-lasting relationship, by the way. "Briefly, they were lovers" basically means that they were romantically involved for some short period of time.

Comment: "in that it is" or "when" convey more or less the same meaning in this case. "While" would also fit.

Comment: see my edit, I hope it clarifies it a bit. :)

Comment: @oerkelens, +1  for the answer! user4550, which part of oerkelens' answer do you not understand?

Comment: So it means when it talks about their friendship and our mourning process, it is raw and complex?

Comment: Yes. When it talks about those things, it is raw and complex. But maybe it is also raw and complex when other things are mentioned. Maybe it talks about nothing else. We simply do not know :)

Comment: I don't know if I'm a bit too tired or something, but I couldn't fully understand this answer. As far as I can tell, the sentence is ambiguous, so it can be read in a few ways (though all of them might mean approximately the same thing). Also, I'm not sure that saying "in" stands for "when" is a good idea or not. Of course, we have a phrase like "In 1984, ...", which is about time. But we also have a phrase like "In this way, ...", which is not about time, too.

Comment: "She is irresistible in being so pretty and adorable". Is that sentence more clear?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Locatives  may be used metaphorically, and pretty interchangeably, in speaking of any domain which may be thought of (or actually represented) spatially or temporally. For instance, numbers are neither spatial nor temporal; but in looking at a graph of a function we might say "Look, **here**, at the spike **when** the x-value passes from 1 to 1.5". *In* here may be paraphrased "at those points in the (?text/film?) when (or where) it is addressing ...".

Comment: @DamkerngT, oerkelens: Given that "the piece" here is *entirely* concerned with "thinking through their friendship and how we mourn", it's probably fair to say ***in** thinking through...* here equates to ***in how** it thinks through...* (or ***as** it thinks through*). But for what it's worth, I personally think the phrasing is a bit clumsy.

Comment: @oerkelens: I wouldn't like to have to explain exactly why, but I don't find your *"She is irresistible in being so pretty and adorable"* idiomatically acceptable phrasing at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree it's not pretty. I was struggling to find a "simpler" example.